# Verification of http post

Tags: android

I'm using the following code to post to a Google Form.  If the HTTP response is not successful then the record is not marked as sent from the sqlite database and is resent during the next sync operation.  The problem is I see frequent double posts because a response is not received even though the post was successful.

Is there a better way to confirm the post without creating double posts to the form?

Thanks for your help.

```
private Boolean performPost(String...data){
  prefs = UserData.getPrefs(mContext);
  spreadsheetKey = prefs.getString(UserData.PREF_SPREADSHEET_KEY,"");
  ArrayList<BasicNameValuePair> results = new ArrayList<BasicNameValuePair>();
  HttpPost post = new HttpPost("https://spreadsheets.google.com/spreadsheet/formResponse?hl=en_US&formkey=" + spreadsheetKey);

  int counter = 0;

  for (String s : data){
    results.add(new BasicNameValuePair("entry." + counter + ".single", s));
    counter ++;
  }

 try {
      post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(results));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    // Auto-generated catch block
    Log.e(TAG, "An error has occurred", e);
     }
try {
    //client.execute(post);
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
    StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
    returnCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();

    Log.d(TAG, statusLine+ "\n"+ returnCode + " " + String.valueOf(post.getEntity()));
    response.getEntity().consumeContent();

} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    // Auto-generated catch block

    Log.e(TAG, "client protocol exception", e);
} catch (IOException e) {
    // Auto-generated catch block
    Log.e(TAG, "io exception", e);
}

if (returnCode == 200){
    return true;
}else{
    resultTxt = SYNC_UNSUCCESSFUL_HTTP_ERROR;
    Log.e(TAG,"post unsuccessful, http code :" + String.valueOf(returnCode));

    sendBroadcast();

    return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: where is 'returnCode' defined ? maybe you have a memory leak ?

Comment: returnCode is defined at the beginning of the class.

Comment: are there other methods using it ? I suspect you have a memory leak. define it inside the methods

Comment: I've made the changes and will test for a couple of days.  I'll let you know how the testing goes.  Thanks!